# Why does downloading the iso take so long?

Tags: download

Why does a 1gb file take so long to download? My download speed is fine so I see no reason for the download to take so long unless the servers are just bad? Is there no mirror that I can download from that isn't trash?

Answer (score 0):

Some numbers would be helpful. You can try to download using torrents - here's a page with some [magnet links](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2018/10/elementary-os-50-juno-released-download-iso-torrents.html?m=1). (Verify checksums if you want)

Alternatively use a download accelerator that can open multiple connections e.g. IDM on Windows.